# start pace.js right after click button for call ajax and $http

Tags: ajax, http, progress-bar, pace

I have used pace.js as my progress bar but it is shown only when page loads or reloads and the times when it wants to load data received from ajax or $http calls, not before that. what should I do to start pace right after click button?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out from the API doc that you can use the Pace.restart() function on button click
e.g
`